# Adding CsWinRT nuget breaks using Windows.System namespace

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, .net-5

I've created a .NET 5.0 project, one of the [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.analyticsinfo?view=winrt-19041) I have is on this API:

```
AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily
```

After installing [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts), I'm able to use this API. Then, I needed to install the [Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT/) package to resolve this error:

```
Error   NETSDK1130  Referencing a Windows Metadata component directly when targeting 
.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0 is not supported. 

Use the C#/WinRT projection tool (https://aka.ms/cswinrt) or a provided projection for this target.
```

After installing this, I no longer have access to the `Windows.System.Profile` namespace to call the `AnalyticsInfo` API:

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'System' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: You don't need to add Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT. Just remove Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts (unneeded now) and make sure your .csproj file contains this: `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>` (version to be adapted to the version of windows you want to target, and you can't use Visual Studio UI for editing that)

Comment: Hey - adding the versions worked alright but I had to keep the CsWinRT reference. Feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With .NET 5, built-in support for WinRT APIs in .NET is removed (because it's Windows specific) , so we can't use  `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` any more.

The solution as explained here [Built-in support for WinRT is removed from .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/interop/5.0/built-in-support-for-winrt-removed#recommended-action) is to

> Remove references to the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts package.
> Instead, specify the version of the Windows APIs that you want to
> access via the TargetFramework property of the project. For example:
>
> `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFramework>`

Note with that in place, there's no need to manually add a reference to C#/WinRT (`Microsoft.Windows.CsWinRT`) it should be done automatically and shown as "`Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref`" in the list of Frameworks Dependencies.